# Solve "cannot perform a DML operation inside a query "

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stored-functions, sql-update

The pl SQL script below transfers the amount c of money from account a to b. Why isn't allowed to update the table in the function / how can it be fixed?

```
 create or replace function ueberweisung (a varchar2, b varchar2,c number)   

 RETURN varchar2 IS   
 k1 number; -- Variablendeklaration   
 k2 number;  

 BEGIN   

 SELECT saldo into k1   
 FROM konto   
 WHERE konto_nr=a;   

 SELECT saldo into k2   
 FROM konto   
 WHERE konto_nr=b;   

 k1:=k1-c;  
 k2:=k2+c;  

 update konto 
 set saldo = case
when konto_nr=a then k1
when konto_nr=b then k2
end;
commit;

 RETURN (c ||'Eur überwiesen von Konto ' || a || 'a uf Konto ' || b);   
 END ueberweisung;
```

Comment: A function is intended just to return data, not to change the data. Basically, it's just a reader, not a writer. Why don't you use a stored procedure?

Comment: It is allowed to update the table from the function. (It's convention to use a procedure rather than a function if you're modifying data, but it is allowed). What is not allowed is to then call that function from SQL. You can still call it (or a procedure) from PL/SQL, but not from a SQL context, You haven't shown how you call it, but the error means you've made it part of a SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of [Restrictions on PL/SQL Functions](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch17_04.htm)

> in order to guard against nasty side effects and upredictable behavior, the Oracle Server makes it impossible for your stored function in SQL to take any of the following actions: The **stored function may not modify database tables**.
>
> - **It cannot execute an INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement.**

Use [PL/SQL procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/08_subs.htm) instead

> PL/SQL has two types of subprograms, procedures and functions. Generally, you **use a procedure to perform an action and a function to compute a value.**